# Fonts not found: React-slick + nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, next.js, react-slick

I am trying to use [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) inside a [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/) project. The carousel works fine but I have some problems importing the fonts used in the css files.

I have tried the following:

`npm install slick-carousel`

and imported the css in the component where the react-slick module is used:

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

When i run the application I get the following error in the network log:

`404 Not found` on both `slick.woff` and `slick.ttf`

I found some other responses where they have added the following to the next.config.js:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withFonts(withSass(withCss({
  env: {
    environment: 'development'
  },
  enableSvg: true,
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    })
    return config
  },
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  },
})))
```

I've tried both with and without the `withFonts` module.

If i add the direct urls in the `<Head>`it will work:

```
 <Head>
        <>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
        </>
 </Head>
```

But will rather get the fonts to work instead.

Anyone with some suggestion to get the fonts to load in Nextjs?

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but I solved it another way.

As I am going to style most of the stuff that requires fonts, i decided to just copy the css from `slick-carousel` and delete all font references. Override arrow left, arrow right as well as the dots.

Not a solution on the problem stated above but fix my issue.

Comment: Where did you find the css to copy for slick carousel

Comment: On the quick start in their docs (https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started) you can find links to the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Pasting both files in public directory with next font installed should resolve 404 error